# How to share Alsa devices between users?

Tags: ubuntu, alsa

I lost the ability to share `Alsa` sound between users even if only one is logged in.

According to [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup) `ConsoleKit` integration should be used instead direct ownership of the device. After I removed users from `audio` group as advised, normal users cannot play sounds but `root` can.

For example, `mpg123` reports this for other users:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
```

Other information:

```
$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: Permission denied

$ getfacl /dev/snd/** | grep user
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
user::rwx
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
user::rw-
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add user to group **audio**, then run alsactl whith flag **no lock**

```
alsactl -L init
```

Reboot